# Truth in a vacuum and Emes

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, emes-truth-honesty

The rules of mathematical logic classify a [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) as being true.  Therefore, if I say "All of my answers with score >500 have been accepted," that is a true statement according to the rules of logic.

Does Judaism acknowledge this kind of statement as being either true or false?  Would [מדבר שקר תרחק](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9884#v=7) tell me to avoid making such statements?

Comment: They also have not been accepted

Comment: http://www.torah.org/learning/integrity/distfalsehood.html

Comment: It probably depends if your listeners are knowledgeable in logical discourse or not.

Comment: Probably involves גניבת דעת.

Comment: @user6591 What is deceptive about it if it is true? Maybe you just tend to misinterpret words, but should that stop me from speaking accurately?

Comment: @Double if i misinterpret based on my own choice of understanding,that would not be גניבת דעת. If you the speaker chooses misleading words, that would be גניבת דעת. In the example given, the number 500 definately leads the listener to think they exist.

Comment: @user6591 I don't see how it leads to any conclusion other than it is not the case that he has answers with >500 score which are not accepted ([contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)). The statement is completely true and hence has no false implications. What is misleading? The only people I can imagine being misled the way you describe are those who tend to misunderstand things because they unfortunately haven't been taught to think correctly. Do I need to worry about them sufficiently to not say correct things?

Comment: @DoubleAA "The statement is completely true and hence has no false implications" is simply untrue. The most common situation where it does if it is said in response to a question which implies that it was a response to the question, but in fact was just intended to evade the question while giving the impression that it answered it. If the statement in the OP was said in response to a question "Are your highly voted answers always/generally accepted?" it is misleading.

Comment: @Yishai It cannot be objectively misleading! If it was said in response to that question then it is clear the person is not answering the question, assuming both sides are speaking plain simple standard English. If the asker or responder is expecting a certain kind of non-literal/non-standard usage then indeed one could miscommunicate to them, but the same is true if I spoke a language very much like English where _yes_ means no and _no_ means yes. You always need to assume both sides are speaking the same language. Speaking different languages will certainly result in miscommunication.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know why "objectively misleading" (if you mean that as the legal term of art) is the relevant standard for גניבת דעת.

Comment: @Yishai I never said it was. You told me my statement was untrue because it was actually misleading. Apparently you have an objective standard of misleadingness. I have argued this whole time that in the case where you know one person is unfortunately not trained to understand language properly, then tricking them by speaking a different language than theirs (even if correct in yours/the standard's) is lying.

Comment: @Double You are thinking like a Vulcan. This is based on what regular, dare i say normal people would conclude based on the implications of the statement. Rightfully or not.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I didn't say your statement was untrue because it was misleading. I said that completely true statements can have false implications based on context, so something being completely true does not conclude that it is not misleading.

Comment: downvote? [15 c]

Comment: 1. A good point, raising a question of dealing with formal logic in Judaism. IMHO it doesn't. the core of Judaism is the lack of formal logic, which allows for all the Talmudic discussion. 2. Another thing Judaism totally lacks is the methodology of anything. There's no system of what can or can't be claimed and what can or can't be accepted as a valid conclusion. 3. Take just any simple Halacha you know and try to trace it down to its source - is it formally logical? Therefore it's pointless to expect an answer, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know.

But here's an argument possibly supporting allowing making such statements: The Torah discusses the case of a *ben sorer umore* (a rebellious son). The Talmud (*Sanhedrin* 71 *amud* 1] cites an opinion that such a case has never happened and never will. Nonetheless, the Torah discusses what to do if it does happen. That is, the Torah itself is engaging in a sort of vacuous-hypothesis truthtelling.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11415/why-does-rashi-say-i-dont-know :P

Answer (score 0):

While [this blog post](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2007/10/translating.html) is not a definitive answer, he cites Ramba"m's statements at the beginning of Hilchot Yesodei Hatorah, pointing out how Ramba"m uses the word "Emet" in various ways that go beyond the common translation as "truth". Excerpt:

> The Rambam here is not talking about what is True, but about what is
>   Real.
>
> Aside from general accuracy, I think that the difference between the
>   different translations is profound. 'Truth' is an abstract concept
>   that we essentially borrowed from the Greeks. They invented or
>   discovered (not getting into that here) logical rules and postulates
>   which allowed them to categorize statements as being 'true' or
>   'false'. Something which is 'True' corresponds to some kind of Ideal
>   Form, and something which is false does not.
>
> At some point, the Hebrew terms 'emet' and 'sheker' came to correspond
>   to these Greek concepts. As we got used to the Greek way of thinking,
>   it was important to have the vocabulary to communicate it. The problem
>   is obviously that it ends up 'Hellenizing' ideas and statements that
>   appear in early Jewish works. Those early sources are not necessarily
>   concerned with abstractions. The Torah and the Neviim, and Chaza"l in
>   their wake, are amazingly concrete, often expressing abstraction in
>   very 'earthy' ways. They were interested in what's real and what's
>   fake, what's authentic and what's phony, what's original and what's
>   imitation. The problem with lying is not the violation  of some
>   abstract category, but the representation of something which is
>   misleadingly non-real.

As a supporting idea, you often see the term "Emet" following "Chesed", as in this week's parsha in [Breishit 24:49](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=302) where Eliezer asks that Rivka's family perform "Chesed V'Emet". I encourage you to view Ibn Ezra's commentary, there. Essentially, he says that "Chessed" is something that is not required and "Emet" is something done to establish the "chesed". The point is, that Eleizer prefaces this with the word "osim" - to DO, meaning a physical, realistic act. Thus this lends support to the notion that "Emet" is based on physical reality and not just plain "vacuous" concepts of "truth" referring to things that don't exist.

Comment: So am I not allowed to talk about dragons then?  They aren't real.

Comment: @Yez, they [aren't](http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/animals/komodo-dragon)? :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Judaism does accept such a logical construct in halacha.  Heter iska is an example of such a construct.

> If I am a chicken then this money I pay you is profit and not interest

This is a true statement in the empty sense and is accepted as valid by Jewish law. Why such a statement is acceptable [is the subject of a separate question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48346/2205).

Comment: What is that quote from?

Comment: @doubleAA It's not a quote; it's made up to illustrate the logical structure of heter iska.

Comment: Why would you need to do that instead of just quoting the actual Heter Iska? Can you source that this is indeed the logical structure of the Heter Iska? (You can't, because it isn't.)